# How do you skip a file's BOM before parsing it?

Tags: d, byte-order-mark

A Unicode file can contain a [BOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) at the start of the file. `std.file.readText()` will verify that this BOM is appropriate for the encoding it is saving to (string, wstring, dstring) but leaves the BOM as part of the range.

Parsers generally don't expect to be parsing a file but instead just a string which doesn't have a BOM specification since the type is already known.

How do I go about reading a file and removing the BOM if it exists?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way I've identified is to utilize std.encoding to get the BOM and skip over it.

```
import std.file;
auto fileContent = readText(file);
```

As Jonathan mentioned, it wouldn't work for non UTF8 encoding so here is a tested function which works with string, wstring, dstring and tested.

```
import std.traits: isSomeString;

STR skipBom(STR)(STR fileContent) if(isSomeString!STR) {
    import std.encoding : getBOM, BOM;
    import std.algorithm : skipOver;
    import std.traits: CopyTypeQualifiers;
    auto byteArray = cast(CopyTypeQualifiers!(STR, ubyte[]))fileContent;
    if(getBOM(byteArray).schema != BOM.none)
        byteArray.skipOver(getBOM(byteArray).sequence);
    return cast(STR)byteArray;
} unittest {
    string s = "\xEF\xBB\xBFTesting UTF8";
    assert(skipBom(s) == "Testing UTF8");
} unittest {
    wstring s = [0xFEFF,'T', 'e', 's', 't', 'i', 'n', 'g', ' ', 'U', 'T', 'F', '1', '6'];
    assert(skipBom(s) == "Testing UTF16");
} unittest {
    dstring s = [0x0000FEFF,'T', 'e', 's', 't', 'i', 'n', 'g', ' ', 'U', 'T', 'F', '3', '2'];
    assert(skipBom(s) == "Testing UTF32");
}
```

Comment: That's only going to work if it's UTF-8 or another encoding that sometimes gets away with acting like it's UTF-8 (e.g. UTF-7). If `readText` has no template argument, it validates that the text is valid UTF-8. `readText!wstring` validates that it's UTF-16, and `readText!dstring` validates that it's UTF-32. UTF-8 almost never has a BOM, and if it's UTF-7, there's a good chance that `readText` will throw. So, while the code as-is will remove a UTF-7 or UTF-8 BOM if present and the text is valid UTF-8, it probably won't work. Using `readText!wstring` with that code should work for UTF-16 though.

Comment: If UTF-7 is a concern, could look for the BOM in a UTF-7 encoding:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Byte_order_marks_by_encoding